# Unreachable code FOR

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

I have this code and I want to improve it. I want to delete the goto

```
string NameOfFile = tbOpenFile.Text;

FileStream ReadStream = new FileStream(NameOfFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

StreamReader r_Read = new StreamReader(ReadStream);
i = 1;
lb1.Items.Clear();

for (; ; i++)
{
    tbOpenFile.Text = r_Read.ReadLine();
    lines[i] = tbOpenFile.Text;

    lb1.Items.Add(lines[i]);

    if (r_Read.EndOfStream.Equals(true)) 
       goto next;
}

next:
{
    textBox2.Text = r_Read.EndOfStream.ToString();
    ReadStream.Close();
}
```

I've tried to do like this using if

```
string NameOfFile = tbOpenFile.Text;
FileStream ReadStream = new FileStream(NameOfFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

StreamReader r_Read = new StreamReader(ReadStream);
i = 1;

lb1.Items.Clear();

for (; ; i++)
{
    tbOpenFile.Text = r_Read.ReadLine();
    lines[i] = tbOpenFile.Text;

    lb1.Items.Add(lines[i]);

    if (r_Read.EndOfStream.Equals(true)) 
    {
        textBox2.Text = r_Read.EndOfStream.ToString();
        ReadStream.Close();
    }
}
```

and like try like this using while

```
string NameOfFile = tbOpenFile.Text;
FileStream ReadStream = new FileStream(NameOfFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

StreamReader r_Read = new StreamReader(ReadStream);
i = 1;

lb1.Items.Clear();

while(r_Read.EndOfStream.Equals(true))
{
    for (; ; i++)
    {
        tbOpenFile.Text = r_Read.ReadLine();
        lines[i] = tbOpenFile.Text;

        lb1.Items.Add(lines[i]);
    }

    continue;

    textBox2.Text = r_Read.EndOfStream.ToString();
    ReadStream.Close();
}
```

but I always get an error

> unreachable code

Comment: The code after `continue;` does not execute - that is your unreachable code.

Comment: if (r_Read.EndOfStream.Equals(true)) break;

Comment: Goto's are **very** bad practice. I wonder why this isn't the first comment.

Comment: @bytecode77 the OP is trying to get rid of the `goto`.

Comment: `while (!r_Read.EndOfStream) {...}`  and delete the `for` altogether.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp That's what I was saying. See my answer.

Comment: Or, [File.ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in `for (; ; i++)`
It will increment forever, put a condition in for your for loop.

Answer (score 1):

The way you handle files is not very common. You can achieve everything a lot easier using a **while** loop:

```
using (StreamReader streamReader = File.OpenText(path))
{
    while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = streamReader.ReadLine();
        // Process "line" here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code after `continue;` does not execute - that is your unreachable code. Instead `break` the loop once you reach the end of your file.

Try the below - I've removed the `while` loop as it isn't needed.

```
StreamReader r_Read = new StreamReader(ReadStream);
i = 1;

lb1.Items.Clear();

for (; ; i++)
{
    tbOpenFile.Text = r_Read.ReadLine();
    lines[i] = tbOpenFile.Text;

    lb1.Items.Add(lines[i]);
    if (r_Read.EndOfStream.Equals(true))
    {
        break; // exits the loop.
    }
}

textBox2.Text = r_Read.EndOfStream.ToString();
ReadStream.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to break out of the loop.

```
for (; ; i++)
{
    tbOpenFile.Text = r_Read.ReadLine();
    lines[i] = tbOpenFile.Text;

    lb1.Items.Add(lines[i]);

    if (r_Read.EndOfStream.Equals(true)) 
    {
        textBox2.Text = r_Read.EndOfStream.ToString();
        ReadStream.Close();
        break;
    }
}
```